# How to send email based on date time in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, delayed-job

I am having a "send email" functionality in my application which sends email to the email addresses.

Later a new functionality is added where when the user checks on "Send email later" radio button, selects date and time and clicks on send email button so that the email is sent at particular time.
For this I added a field into database with column "send_reports_at", added to controller and required actions.

*The date time is stored as : "2016-11-01 16:15".*

How to add the condition of sending email based on the date time in my application(I am new to delayed job and all)?
Please help.

This is my view:

```
<%= f.input :additional_emails, :label => false, :input_html => {:id => 'sponge_contacts', :placeholder => 'Separate emails by comma', :class => 'deliver_page_email', :type => 'text', :rows => 2, :style=> 'width:300px; border-color:#ccc; font-size:13px; padding:10px 0 0 10px; width: 295px; height: 110px; resize: none;'} %>
<input type="radio" id="send_email_0" name="send_email" value="now" checked> Send email now<br>
<input type="radio" id="send_email_1" name="send_email" value="later"> Send email later<br>

    <%= f.input :send_reports_at,:label => false, :input_html => {:placeholder => 'Click here to select date and times', :class => 'deliver_page_email', :type => 'text', :rows => 2} %>
    <% content_for :javascript do %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $( function() {
    $( "#report_send_reports_at" ).datepicker();
  } );

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#report_send_reports_at").hide();

                $("#send_email_0, #send_email_1").bind('change click',function(){
                    toggleResult();
                });

            });
            function toggleResult(){
                result = $("[name='send_email']:checked").val();
                if(result == "later"){
                    $("#report_send_reports_at").show();
                }else{
                    $("#report_send_reports_at").hide();
                }
            }

        </script>
    <% end %>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Send Now", '#', :class => "pink_button _round_5", :id => 'send_now_button' %>
```

This is my controller method:

```
def send_report_email
    send_to_agents = params.has_key?("send_to_agents") && params["send_to_agents"] == "true"
    if @report.photos.empty?
      Screenshot.delay.new(@user.id, @report.id, Rails.application.config.custom.indicator_screenshot_bucket)
    else
      Screenshot.delay.new(@user.id, @report.id, "photo_screenshots")
    end
     Screenshot.delay.new(@user.id, @report.id, Rails.application.config.custom.report_screenshot_bucket)
    if @report.update_attributes(params[:report])
      set_photo_position(false)
      @report.save   
      if send_to_agents
        @report.update_attribute(:duplicable, true)
        @good_emails, @bad_emails, @unsubscribed_emails = @user.account.users.map(&:email), [], []
      else
        @good_emails, @bad_emails, @unsubscribed_emails = filter_emails(@report.additional_emails)
        @user.delay.add_new_contacts(@good_emails)
      end
      @good_emails.each do |email|
        send_to_agents == true ? ReportMailer.delay.additional_emails(email, @user, @report, "A new report is available: #{@report.title}") : ReportMailer.delay.additional_emails(email, @user, @report)
      end
      ReportMailer.delay.report_sent(@user, @report, @good_emails, @bad_emails, @unsubscribed_emails)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render :json => { :success => true, :report_id => @report.id, :redirect => user_reports_url(current_user), :notice => 'Report was successfully sent!' } }
    end

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function (for instance a class method for ReportMailer) that sends all of the email whose scheduled time matches or is less than the current time, then set a [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) job to use [rails runner](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-runner) to run that function as often as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

use **deliver_later** method with **wait_until** option
like this

```
.deliver_later(wait_until: your_stored_datetime)
```